# How do I programmatically change ASP.NET ajax AccordionPane with javascript?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, accordionpane

I've got an asp.net ajax style AccordionPane control that I am trying to get/set based on some user interactions. However it seems not let me do this with javascript:

```
function navPanelMove() {  
  var aPane = $get('ctl00_Accordion1_AccordionExtender_ClientState');  
  openPaneID = aPane.get_SelectedIndex();  // doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use **$find('behaviorId')**

You want the **AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionBehavior** object, not the DOM elements

Comment: To get the behaviorId in AjaxControlToolkit v4.1, this is what I used:`var behaviorId = $get("<%= myAccordion.ClientID%>").AccordionBehavior._id;`